# running the process in a background

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, process

If I have have a process on UNIX and if i want to run it in the background and even if i close my terminal I need it to be running in the background until it completes.

How do I do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/closing-a-terminal-without-killing-its-children

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).

Answer (score 0):

You could run it with nohup. [nohup wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

[edit]
Ah ignacio you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&` in the end of the command.

Check [this](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afnz.html).

Comment: When you run this the terminal will be come open for input again, but as soon as you close the terminal, its child process will also die.